# Filtering image collection based on list of dates using Google Earth Engine Python API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I would like to extract an image collection of some days.

For instance, if I want to extract an image collection between two dates, I can simply do:

```
START = '2010-08-01'
END = '2010-09-15'
cover = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MYD11A1').filter(ee.Filter.date(START, END))
```

What I would like to do is to filter based on a list of dates and do something like the following:

```
DATES = ['2010-08-01', '2010-08-12', '2010-09-01']
cover = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MYD11A1').filter(ee.Filter.date(DATES))
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added a 'Date' property to the ImageCollection, and then filter for specific dates:

```
var START = '2010-08-01'
var END = '2010-09-15'

var DATES = ['2010-08-01', '2010-08-12', '2010-09-01']

var addTime = function(x) {
  return x.set('Date', ee.Date(x.get('system:time_start')).format("YYYY-MM-dd"))}
  
var cover = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MYD11A1')
            .filter(ee.Filter.date(START, END))
            .map(addTime)
            .filter(ee.Filter.inList('Date',ee.List(DATES)))
print(cover)
```

Comment: You're welcome my friend

Comment: thank you, I adapted the code for python